# photo tagging using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, photo-tagging

How can I implement a photo tagging feature in C#?  I want to develop similar functionality to sites like Orkut and Facebook.

Comment: I suspect you're going to need to provide more information: vague questions yield vague answers.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. What are you stuck on? You want to tag areas of a photo? What have you tried?

Comment: Ya I want to add tags to areas of a photo

Comment: Always comeup with something you did. It will persuade the other users to provide you a successful answer.. No one will bother too much to do the every thing for you

Answer (score 5):

Just think a bit more and break the problem into sections.

Tagging is just marking an area and map a name for that area. So you just need to keep a single coordinate to keep your tag location, say the top left corner (And assume a fixed size of a square : that is the tag area) and the name that mapped with the area. You may use any form/image coordinate manipulation capability with a simple mouse down event.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one, it might be of some help:

[Facebook Style Photo Tag (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Facebook_Style_Photo_Tag.aspx)